# KnexJS select all records from current year

Tags: javascript, node.js, dayjs, knex.js

I just want to be able to select all records from this current year, like, we're in 2020, **select all records which created_at year is greater than 2020**.

```
const current_year = dayjs().format('YYYY');
```

I'm using `dayjs` to get the current year. How can i compare the row year of creation with the current year with `knexjs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Year` function of your DB (I guess that it has it, `MySql` has it).

```js
const current_year = dayjs().format('YYYY');

const results = await knex('tableName').whereRaw('Year(dateCreated) = ?', [current_year]);
```

This will execute

```sql
Select * from tableName Where Year(dateCreated) = `2020`;
```

Comment: I got an error ```Unknown column 'Year(created_at)' in 'where clause'``` :(

Comment: you solution actually worked, i just had to change ```where``` to ```whereRaw``` like this: ```.whereRaw(`Year(created_at) = ${current_year}`);```